# perl: how to make the script to print 'pattern matched'

Tags: perl

```
$out="MMNT123 out in a1 a2";
    if($out=m(MM\w+\s\w+))
        print 'pattern matched';
    else
        print 'pattern not matched';
```

How do i get 'pattern matched' as a output...?

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, if/else blocks must have braces. You also need to use the `=~` operator:

```
if($out =~ m(MM\w+\s\w+)) {
    print 'pattern matched';
} else {
    print 'pattern not matched';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error because you have omitted the braces on your `if .. else ...` statement.

```
$out = "MMNT123 out in a1 a2";
if ($out = m(MM\w+\s\w+)) {
    print 'pattern matched';
} else {
   print 'pattern not matched';
}
```

But that still doesn't work as you are using the assignment operator (`=`) where you should be using the binding operator (`=~`).

```
$out = "MMNT123 out in a1 a2";
if ($out =~ m(MM\w+\s\w+)) {
    print 'pattern matched';
} else {
   print 'pattern not matched';
}
```

For completeness, I should point out that:

```
$out = m(MM\w+\s\w+)
```

Is actually:

```
$out = ($_ =~ /MM\w+\s\w+/)
```

I.e. "match the contents of `$_` against the regular expression and set `$out` to a true value if it matched or a false value if it doesn't match". I guess the contents of `$_` didn't match your regex so `$out` was always getting a false value.

Comment: As is often the case, `use warnings` can explain more: `Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)`

Answer (score 0):

not necessary in braces for if

```
print 'pattern matched' if $out =~ /MM\w+\s\w+/;
```